# Converting a HashMap into Clojure map performs not as excepted from a java call

Tags: java, clojure, hashmap

I'm very new to Clojure. I want to pass a `List<HashMap<String,String>>` to a Clojure function in which I want to use the inner HashMaps as regular Clojure maps but I cannot get values from the map with using the :key function (which works fine for a regular Clojure map) I use the into {} function but it does not make what I except it to make. What is what I do wrong?
(Note: This is a demostration test code just to see the behaviour)

Java code:

```
package com.experimental.clojure.java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.experimental.clojure.test.ConvertTest;

public class Test_Cloj_Convert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, String>> columns = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> col1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        col1.put("name", "ID");
        col1.put("type", "int");
        col1.put("pos", "0");
        Map<String, String> col2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        col2.put("name", "Name");
        col2.put("type", "string");
        col2.put("pos", "2");
        Map<String, String> col3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        col3.put("name", "Description");
        col3.put("type", "enum");
        col3.put("pos", "1");
        columns.add(col1);
        columns.add(col2);
        columns.add(col3);

        ConvertTest scripter = new ConvertTest();
        System.out.println(scripter.conv(columns));
    }
}
```

Clojure code

```
(ns com.experimental.clojure.test.ConvertTest
  (:gen-class
   :name com.experimental.clojure.test.ConvertTest
   :methods [
             [conv [java.util.List] String]
  ])
  (:import [java.util List] [java.util HashMap])  
)

(defn conv
    [columns]
    (println columns)
    (println (first columns))
    (println (:type (first columns)))
    (println (into {} (first columns)))
    (println (:type (into {} (first columns))))
)

(defn -conv
  [this columns]
  (conv columns)
)
```

And the (suprising) output

```
#<ArrayList [{name=ID, type=int, pos=0}, {name=Name, type=string, pos=2}, {name=Description, type=enum, pos=1}]>
#<HashMap {name=ID, type=int, pos=0}>
nil
{name ID, type int, pos 0}
nil
null
```

What I've excepted for the third println the return the string "int".
And in the fourth println it is obvious that the HashMap is not properly converted into Clojure map. Can you help what to do for the successful conversion? (I know I could use the get() function of the HashMap but it would be more comfortable to able to use it as a Clojure map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues I see:

- Your conv function is returning nil, because println is the last statement and that returns nil
- ":type" is a Clojure keyword which is not equal to the String key "type" - hence the lookups are failing to find the value you want

Comment: I understand the last null value. That's no problem. I did not know that :type like this is a keyword, so I tried the same example reading the key :name or :pos. The result is the same. So unless they're reserved words too it is not a good explanation. (And it would be strange not be able to use specific words as name or type as keys for a map).

Comment: (Time limit reached) And the issue 3, for me it is not trivial why the (println (into {} (first columns))) line gives back the {name ID, type int, pos 0} structure which is not a regular map.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now more and it was asking a silly thing.
Sorry for all, but I was under the impression that in Clojure the following two structures are indentical. 
`{"a" 1, "b" 2, "c" 3}` and `{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}` They are not and I tried to use the wrong method for getting the data from the map.
I tried with using `(println ((into {} (first columns)) "pos"))` and it works fine.
I'm sorry for not realizing this sooner.

However, if I may ask again. What is the real difference between them? Right now I only have a vague idea about that.

Comment: "a" and :a have some diffrence in semantics but the can be exchanged most of the time. So a keyword is often used for keys in a map because they have faster lookup times (faster to compair, js for example only has strings and that limits performance) and keywords implement IFn so the can used as functions to look themselfs up (:bla {:bla 5}) will return 5 this is not the case with strings. Keywords alsow have optimal namespaces ::keyword-with namespace (not often used). http://clojure.org/data_structures
Alsow Keywords are used if you mark something say you classify sizes :big :small :mini.

Comment: This might be useful: `(name :hello) ;=> "hello"`